# LiteDB.Shell cannot open my database file

Tags: litedb

I have database file called `db.MyDb` and I was able to open it before and also insert some database. Currently this file has important data and due to some file uploaded to this database wrongly so I need to remove that file, but I cannot open the database file ! @mbdavid

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your file `db.MyDb` is in v1.0.4 version and if you don't want update to v2 use v1 database dll version (including v.1 Shell tool).

If you want update your file to v2, run (using v2 shell):

`LiteDB.Shell.exe db.MyDb --upgrade db_v2.MyDB`